# Lazy loading and nested router outlets

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I am trying to have lazy loading work with nested router outlets but without luck.

Is this supported at all in Angular 4?

This is my use case:

There seems to be a problem when using router navigation with lazy loaded modules. This works fine if I remove lazy loading. But here is my setup according to lazy loading modules:

In my app.template I have the main router-outlet defined.

I have the following root app router

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: './user/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
  }
]
```

When the profile module is loaded into the main router-outlet it will display a page with two routing tabs and an inside profile.module I have the following child routes defined

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'subPath1', loadChildren: '../subModule1/subModule1.module#SubModule1Module' },
            { path: 'subPath2', loadChildren: '../subModule2/subModule2.module#SubModule2Module' },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),
     ....
    ]
}
```

Inside profile.template I have routing tab defined like this

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
          <a class="tab-label" md-tab-link [routerLink]="'subPath1'" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            Sub path 1
          </a>
          <a class="tab-label" md-tab-link [routerLink]="'subPath2'" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            Sub path 2
          </a>
        </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I route e.g. to /user/:id/subPath2 I would expect subModule2 to be loaded into the router-outlet of the md-tab-nav-bar but instead, it is being loaded into the main application router-outlet. This closes the profile.component and displays only submodule2 instead of displaying it inside the tab.

Any idea why this is not working with lazy loading modules?

Comment: Seems you forgot to add link to your working example that will help us to understand your issue

Comment: Sorry about that, added the working example.

Comment: Would be great if you provided plunker like this https://plnkr.co/edit/rGHV1X5jTTuaYms4WwuW?p=preview As you can see all works as was expected

Comment: @yurzui thanks alot, I will have a look :)

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the example demo it is very clear and I could quickly spot the problem, The problem was I didn't specify  the MdTabsModule.forRoot(). You can move this to an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: I'm having this problem too (child route is loading into app outlet instead of parent's outlet, even though URL looks right), but I'm not using MdTabs. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @redOctober13 it´s been a while I did this and Angular has been updated multiple times. I recommend creating a new question and describing your problem where you are not using MdTabs .Good luck!

Comment: Got it. I was trying to use both a `''` route in the parent with `children`, and do my lazy-loaded route on the same level as the empty route (thinking that `loadChildren` would take care of it), but it works when I just move my lazy-loaded route inside the `children` object: `children: [{path: 'child', loadChildren: 'child-module#childModule'}]`